# Create a pointer inside a constructor to point to the instance of the class in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I'm a bit confused with these C++ pointers and I would like to know if it's possible to create a pointer inside a constructor that will point to the instance of the class (something on the lines of the following).

```
class Room{
public:  
    Room();  
    ~Room();  
private:  
    Room* ptrToSelf;  
};  

Room::Room(){  
    ptrToSelf = &(what should I write in here to have the pointer point to it)  
}
```

I know this might sound crazy (newbie here), but I just wanted to know if it is possible. Could someone please explain this to me.
Many thanks

Edit:
Thank you everyone for answering me so fast. I was asking because I wanted to use a public `Room*::getPointer();` method to return the pointer for the class. I have a character that moves from room to room and I'm using pointers to achieve this. I'm getting the input from the user in form of string and I can't pass that string to the function to `character.moveTo(const Room*)` method I created. I need a way to "convert" the string into a pointer for the class so that I could pass the pointer to the method.

Edit:
I was thinking of implementing a method that will return the pointer for the object based on a string type parameter:

```
Room::Room* getPointer(const string &nameOfRoom){  
    //I can't use this return statement as the following error  
    //Error: 'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member function  
    return this;
```

Edit (hopefully last one):
Is this returning what I'm looking for?

```
Room::Room* getPointer(const string &nameOfRoom){    
    return &Room();  
}
```

or it's returning the address of a new Room?
Thank you

Comment: Seriously you don't need to hold a reference to yourself as you have a this pointer always implicitly, the real question is why do you need this?

Comment: If you can find `ptrToSelf`, you don't need it. And if you need it, how would you know where to look for it?

Comment: If `ptrToSelf` is an instance member variable, then the expression `ptrToSelf` is actually shorthand for `this->ptrToSelf`. So if `this` is unavailable, so is `ptrToSelf`. The idea, I'm guessing, is to look up a room by name from some internal data structure. If so, then when you find the room in question, simply return its address. BTW, you can't write `return &Room();`. That will create a temporary instance of Room, immediately destroy it, and then return its address.

Comment: It's difficult to assist any further, since I don't understand how the `nameOfRoom` parameter is supposed to be used. You don't use it in any of your sample code, and there's no mention of how you store rooms in your program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the implicit `this` parameter:

```
ptrToSelf = this;
```

Or, even better (ignoring the fact that `ptrToSelf` is a rather silly idea to begin with):

```
Room::Room() : ptrToSelf(this) { }
```

**EDIT:** @BenjaminLindley drew my attention to the fact that there will be issues with certain other member functions. In particular, the copy constructor won't behave correctly by default (`ptrToSelf` will simply be copied from the source instance, so both instances will end up pointing to the one). You may therefore need to provide a copy constructor that ensures `ptrToSelf` is assigned correctly. The base case is this:

```
Room::Room(const Room& room) : ptrToSelf(this) { … }
```

You also need to worry about the assignment operator, but as long as it simply invokes the copy constructor, you'll be fine. The following general-purpose implementation will do the trick:

```
Room& operator=(Room room) { swap(room); return *this; }
void swap(Room& room) { /* Swap rooms… */ }
```

(P.S.: It should be `class Room {…`, not `class Room(){…`.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll modify the provided example as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to do that as your class will have an implicit this pointer

```
this; // can be called anywhere in your class to access yourself
```

Answer (score 2):

use the this keyword

ptrToSelf = this;

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a pointer to the object already, why do you need another?  I guess if you really want it, `ptrToSelf = this;` would work.

Check out [all](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr035.htm) [of](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dddwwd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) [these](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/87-the-hidden-this-pointer/) [links](http://login2win.blogspot.com/2008/05/c-this-pointer.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

ptrToSelf = this;

I'm on my phone so apologies for briefness, will add detail later if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

C++ has a default pointer to point to an instance of a class.  You can use the `this` pointer not only in the constructor, but also in the instance methods. 
Look at the following code excerpt below:

```
class Room {
   public :
      Room(int width); //constructor
      ~Room(); // destructor

      //public instance functions
      int getWidth();
      void setWidth (int width);
  private:
      int width;
 };

 Room::Room (int width) {
      this->width = width;
 }
 Room::~Room () { }

 void Room::setWidth (int width) { 
      this->width = width;
 }

 int Room::getWidth () {
     return this->width;
 }
```

Comment: Newbie question again: what is the purpose of using a `setWidth` method when your `width` is a public member?

Comment: Well, I was just emphasizing about the use of this pointer. But yes, you will normally set the width as private / protected, instead of public. If it is public, then you can access it directly (not using function).

Comment: Thank you. I'm using the `this` pointer everywhere I need to in my code as it's much easier (as you pointed out with the `width`). Cheers

Comment: Glad that it helped. Vote up for this if this answer helps.