# Return the class pointer by using a public function in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, return

I'm trying to return the class pointer by using a public function that takes a string as its parameter. I'm not sure how it's done (the correct way). This is what I have:

```
Room::Room* getPointer(const string &nameOfRoom){    
    return &Room();  
}
```

If I use this construct, am I returning the correct pointer or the pointer to a new instance my function is creating?
Thank you

Sorry everyone for not being very clear about my intentions. I have a Room with a list of pointers to other Room(s) inside. In my opinion that should look like a graph (hope it is one). I have a character which is "navigating" the graph by using the pointers in the list. I'm getting the user's input in form of strings. If my user says "move to bedroom" I would like to pass the "bedroom" as a parameter to a function so that I can somehow get the pointer that is pointing to the bedroom in my list.
I'm not sure I explained it correctly, so please excuse the 'newbiness' and lack of previous explanations.
Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.  What do you want the returned pointer to point at?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, the intentions are not clear,but the code is clearly wrong....

Comment: Continuation from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711455/create-a-pointer-inside-a-constructor-to-point-to-the-instance-of-the-class-in-c/9711478#9711478

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Of course.  But it's difficult to provide an answer until we know what the intention is...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: sorry for not being clear from the beginning. I've amended my text with a 'proper' explanation.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you are trying to return the pointer to an object then you do that like so.

```
Room* getP(const std::string& sfasd)
{
    return this;
}
```

however it better semantically to do this:

```
Room& getP(const std::string& sfasd)
{
    return *this;
}
```

Also you can always do this:

```
Room r;
Room *rp=&r;
```

finally if what you meant was to create a new room you can do

```
Room& getP(const std::string& name)
{
    return new Room(name);
}

::://else where
std::unique_ptr<Room> room_pointer(getP("hi"));
```

Comment: I'm sorry but my compiler warns me that `Error: 'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member function` for the first 2 solutions you provided. Thanks

Comment: Well, yes; these are obviously supposed to be member functions, written inside the class body. Just how much have you studied about the language?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: My method was written outside of the class body as my lecturer said we should write them outside of the class. The explanation was that if your class is very long, the compiler will get confused and one should expect to have wired problems. Thanks for pointing it out for me.

Comment: It's typical when giving code examples to write member functions as if they went inline, assuming the context of which class they go in is obvious enough. The compiler does not "get confused" by long class bodies, but there are certainly plenty of good organizational reasons to move them out.

Comment: @Adrian: The compiler won't get confused, but you will. The solution: Inside the class you _declare_ the method ("there is a function named `getP`) and outside the class you _define_ it ("here is the function `getP` of class `Room` "). If you do so, the compiler knows that `getP` belongs to a class and has a `this` class pointer.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's most definitely wrong. Most compilers should warn you about this. I'm not sure at all what the intended semantics are for your function, as you haven't been very clear about it, but that is very definitely not it.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear from the beginning. I've amended my text with a 'proper' explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do. 
But first of all, your function is returning the address of a stack based variable which is bad, since once the function returns your pointer will be invalid.

And by the way, you are wasting stack space by passing a string and not using it.... If you are using the microsoft compiler you can turn on level 4 warnings (not on by default) and it will emit a warning about that.

If you want to create a new instance of the Room you simply do this:

```
Room* Room::getPointer()
{
   return new Room();
}
```

So again, I'm not sure what you want, so I can only guess at this point.

Comment: You said I'm wasting stack space: how should I define my functions in such a way that I won't by doing this? Thanks.

Comment: @Adrian: it's more than a waste of stack space, it's probably a bug. Why isn't `nameOfRoom` used?